# Strange errors in my Asp.Net MVC 3 site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unhandled-exception

On my Asp.Net MVC 3 site I have an error logging functionality that sends e-mails to me whenever there's an unhandled error on the site. But recently I have been getting strange errors like the following:

The controller for path '/store/admin/login.php' was not found or does not implement IController.

or

The controller for path '/templates/beez/templateDetails.xml' was not found or does not implement IController

It seems someone is trying to access pages that do not exist on the site. I mean, it is not even a php site...

Any idea what this is? Is it some sort of attack? And if so, is it something to be concerned about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site is being probed for some known weaknesses in various web frameworks.  I wouldn't be particularly worried about it, but it should reinforce that you do need to take security seriously.  Make sure that you're following best practices for security and that you have the latest OS and framework patches installed (on a regular basis).